# Как установить библиотеку "Selenium"?

Tags: c#, selenium

Как правильно установить библиотеку "Selenium" в C# для Visual Studio? Пытался установить сам, по старым видео урокам, но не получилось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используя `NuGet`:

```
Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/

P.S. Я так понимаю `NuGet` еще не пользовались ни разу. ОК. Там очень много всего - так что возьмите на карандаш. 
Есть несколько способов поставить пакет из нюгет. 
Первый - как в комментариях, в обозревателе решений (это где дерево файлов и папок проекта) ищем пункт `Ссылки (Reference)` - щелкаем правой кнопкой и выбираем `Управление пакетами NuGet` - там в поиске находим нужную библиотеку по названию.

Тот же эффект - идем в главное меню студии находим пункт `Средства` -> `Диспетчер пакетов NuGet` ->`Управление пакетами NuGet для решения`.

И третий способ через консоль. Опять идем `Средства` -> `Диспетчер пакетов NuGet` только там выбираем `Консоль диспетчера пакетов`. Обычно она открывается внизу, там можно вбивать комманды которые вы находите на сайте `nuget` или просто на просторах интернета:

```
Install-Package [PackageName]
```

Пакет проверяет все условия и если они подходят - скачивает либу и добавляет ее в ссылки. Всё - можно пользоваться.

Comment: Можешь пожалуйста сказать более детально.

Comment: @ЛаврикКан правой кнопкой по Reference, выбрать Nuget Package, далее в поиске найти нужную либу.

Comment: а можно как то через саму visual studio это сделать?

Comment: Так через студию и делается. погодите, все конкретно распишу

Comment: @ЛаврикКан, готово

Comment: Простите мне мой французский, но где на https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/4.0.0-alpha05 ссылка на скачивание? Если ткнуть на https://www.selenium.dev/ - "Негры превыше всего!" Все негры - люди! Все люди - равны! Почему - негры превыше всего? Я пионер из СССР... У меня, как и у Дани Багрова, в Африке живут негры. В Нигере и Нигерии - тоже живут негры. Негры = люди. Все люди равны... В чем проблема?